# Connecting data from an array to an object by using a middleman object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Is there a way to connect `queued_Dr` to `upcoming_appointments` by using `all_appointments`

What would be the best approach to this problem?

```js
var queued_Dr = ["Dr.Salazar",["Dr.Connors","Dr.Johnson"],"Dr.Pearson"]


upcoming_appointments =
[{"DOB":"01-27-2002","name":"Judy, W." ,"PCD":"Dr-S"}
    ,{"DOB":"08-15-1995","name":"John, V." ,"PCD":"Dr-C"}
    ,{"DOB":"07-05-1992","name":"David, C.","PCD":"Dr-S"}
    ,{"DOB":"01-15-2002","name":"Anna, S." ,"PCD":"Dr-J"}
    ,{"DOB":"01-15-2002","name":"Jeff, D." ,"PCD":"Dr-P"}]


all_appointments = 
{"0": ["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],
    "1": ["Dr-C","Austin","Dr.Connors"],
    "2": ["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"],
    "3": ["Dr-S","New York","Dr.Salazar"],
    "4": ["Dr-P","San Juan","Dr.Pearson"],
    "5": ["Dr-J","Austin","Dr.Johnson"]}
```

Goal Output

```
"Dr.Salazar" -> "Dr-S"
["Dr.Connors","Dr.Johnson"] -> "Dr-C" or "Dr-J"
"Dr.Pearson"] -> "Dr-P"
```

inputs are `queued_Dr` and `upcoming_appointments.PCD`

```js
//Tried to see if the values where in the same dictionary 

function find_by_exception_name(dr_name) {
    return all_appointments.find((row) => row.upcoming_appointments == dr_name || row.upcoming_appointments.includes(dr_name));
} 
//would return true or false if a Doctors name from queued_Dr and upcoming appointments existed in all_appointments
```

Comment: You have goal output but what is your input? Also, what have you tried and please show us. Sorry, I don't quite understand what you try to do.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my post to include one of my approaches to the problem along with my inputs @ikhvjs

Comment: I'm still not getting how you connect your 3 inputs to the expected output. Maybe because your expected output is not javascript

Comment: I am trying to see if there is a way to use the inputs `queued_Dr` and `upcoming_appointments.PCD` and see if it is in the same line of the object in `all_appointments` but instead of returning true or false Dr.Salazar would return Dr.S.

Comment: Ok, so show us your expected output _in valid javascript_ and im sure its not that hard a question to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you have given to us you don't need `upcoming_appointments` at all. The code below will return to you the desired result.

```
const mapTo = (arrayWithNames) => {
  return arrayWithNames.map(name => {
    if (Array.isArray(name)) {
      return mapTo(name);
    }

    const appointment = Object.values(all_appointments)
      .find(appointment => appointment[2] === name);
    const upcommingAppointment = upcoming_appointments
      .find(currentAppointment => currentAppointment.PCD === appointment[0])

    console.log(`This is the upcomming appointment for your doctor ${JSON.stringify(upcommingAppointment)}`)
    return `${name} -> ${appointment[0]}` 
  })
}
const result = mapTo(queued_Dr)
```

Also, please format your code properly. In JavaScript it is not a good practice to put opening braces on a new line as this might cause an unexpected result in some scenarios.

Edit: I've added the console.log so you can see the proper appointment for your doctor but you haven't explained how you want to use it.